# Bitcoin.org developer reference outdated?

Tags: transactions, block, block-size-increase

i just can't understand if bitcoin.org developer reference is outdated or not. for example here (https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#raw-transaction-format) we can see: "As of Bitcoin Core 0.9.3 (October 2014), all transactions use the version 1 format described below. (Note: transactions in the block chain are allowed to list a higher version number to permit soft forks, but they are treated as version 1 transactions by current software.)" it's right or it's an old reality?
or here (https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#serialized-blocks) we can read on the first 2 line that blocks must be serialized under 1MB size or less but i know on the current version blocks can be up to 2MB so i can't understand which one is the right answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

> "As of Bitcoin Core 0.9.3 (October 2014), all transactions use the version 1 format described below. (Note: transactions in the block chain are allowed to list a higher version number to permit soft forks, but they are treated as version 1 transactions by current software.)" it's right or it's an old reality?

Both. It is talking about the state of affairs in October 2014, which is old. However it also states that the information dates from back then, so it is technically correct.

Since the activation of BIP 68 in July 2016, transactions with version 2 are relevant to the network rules, so the information could clearly be updated.

> or here (https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#serialized-blocks) we can read on the first 2 line that blocks must be serialized under 1MB size or less but i know on the current version blocks can be up to 2MB so i can't understand which one is the right answer.

That information is clearly outdated since the introduction of Segregated Witness (SegWit) in August 2017. The concept of size of a block is no longer relevant, and replaced with block weight (which counts some bytes in a block more than others) limited to 4000000. In theory this means the total serialized size of specially constructed blocks can be up to 3.9 MB, but for blocks limited to common transactions it's closer to 2 MB.

> i just can't understand if bitcoin.org developer reference is outdated or not.

Some parts are, others aren't. It's a resource maintained by a community, so I'm sure they would appreciate help to keep things up to date: https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its outdated. In [GetHashesPerSec](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#gethashespersec) section, it talked about Bitcoin 0.16.0 which is a recent release.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Parts of the site may be outdated, as evidenced above. A better answer would clear the confusion between the two texts on the site.